# Usuários de outras plataformas irão ver as fontes do meu site?

Tags: html, css, font

A pergunta é simples: Tenho um site, a fonte padrão dele é a **Segoe UI** normal, e a **Segoe UI Light**, o site usa apenas essas duas. No Windows, o site apareceu corretamente e sem problemas, agora tenho dúvidas que se entrarem através de um Chrome (pelo Android) ou num Mac OS X, a fonte irá permanecer e não irá mudar?

> Obs: Estou usando o WebAcapella 4 para editar meu site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segoe UI é uma fonte exclusiva do Windows. Se alguém usando Linux ou Mac abrir seu site, vai aparecer a fonte padrão do sistema.

Eu recomendo que você use a fonte Open Sans, que lembra um pouco a fonte Segoe UI e está disponível no Google Fonts. Basta linkar o CSS.

Mais informações: https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans

Para usar a fonte Open Sans normal e bold, basta inserir no código HTML:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

No entanto, se você realmente quiser que todos vejam a fonte Segoe UI independente do sistema operacional, basta incorporar a fonte usando `@font-face`. Veja o CSS do site da Microsoft:

http://www.microsoft.com/surface/assets/css/fonts/all/fonts.css

Mas devido a questões de licença, parece que somente os sites da Microsoft podem incorporar a fonte Segoe UI.